Jacobian of Product Map
Given smooth maps $f:M_1\to N_1$ and $g:M_2\to N_2$, the product map $f\times g:M_1\times M_2\to N_1\times N_2$, $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x),g(y))$ is also a smooth map (all this is discussed in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold).
I also know that, up to suitable isomorphisms, $d(f\times g)_{(p,q)}:T_pM_1\oplus T_q M_2\to T_{f(p)}N_1\oplus T_{g(q)}N_2$ is the product of the linear maps $df_p$ and $dg_q$. See here for example. I am entirely sure of my statement here tbh.
Now noting that the differential of a smooth map (at a point) is represented by the Jacobian of its co-ordinate representation (at the co-ordinate representation of this point), we choose appropriate smooth charts containing the appropriate points and get matrix representations for $df_p$ and $dg_q$.
My question is how to “combine” these matrices to get the Jacobian of $d(f\times g)_{(p,q)}$? Because of the direct sums appearing in the domain of this linear map, I guess that I need to put the Jacobian matrices of $df_p$ and $dg_q$ along the diagonal of a suitably sized matrix with the remaining entries being all $0$'s.

If will be block diagonal, with blocks $df_p$ and $dg_q$.

This is not really a differential geometry problem but rather just a plain linear algebra problem. In particular, consider two finite-dimensional vector spaces $V,W$ with dimensions $n,m$ respectively, and consider two linear maps $T:V\to V$ and $M:W\to W$. We can then construct from these the map
\begin{align*}
T\oplus M:V\oplus W&\to V\oplus W, \\
(v,w)&\mapsto(T(v),M(w))
\end{align*}
Take now a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $V$ and a basis $\{f_1,\dots,f_m\}$ of $W$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ denote the matrix representations of $T$ and $M$ with respect to these bases. We now observe thag these induce a canonical basis $\{(e_1,0),\dots,(e_n,0),(0,f_1),\dots,(0,f_m)\}$. The question now becomes the following: how is the matrix representation of $T\oplus M$ in this basis related to $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{M}$?
To answer this, let us look at the entries of the matrix representation. Take first $j\in\{1,\dots n\}$. Then
$$(T\oplus M)(e_j,0)=(T(e_j),M(0)).$$
Similarly, if $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$, then
$$(T\oplus M)(0,f_j)=(T(0),M(f_j)).$$
By expressing $T(e_j)$ in the basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ and $M(f_j)$ in $\{f_1,\dots,f_m\}$, it then immediately follows from the above that the first $n$ columns of the matrix representation of $T\oplus M$ are the columns of $\mathcal{T}$ with $m$ zeroes adjoined after them, and the last $m$ columns are the columns of $\mathcal{M}$ with $n$ zeroes adjoined before them, i.e. $T\oplus M$ has matrix representation
$$\mathcal{T}\oplus\mathcal{M}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{T} & 0 \\
0 & \mathcal{M}
\end{pmatrix}$$
(as a block matrix).

To apply this to your specific problem, let $(p,q)\in M_1\times M_2$ and let $(U,x),(V,y)$ be charts on $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively with $(p,q)\in U\times V$. Representing then $\mathrm{d}f_p$ and $\mathrm{d}g_q$ in the bases $\{\partial_{x_1}|_p,\dots,\partial_{x_n}|_p\}$ and $\{\partial_{y_1}|_q,\dots,\partial_{y_m}|_q\}$ we get the representation of $\mathrm{d}(f\times g)_{(p,q)}$ as the block diagonal matrix of these matrix representations (with respect to the canonical choice of basis).

Thank you for the answer :)
